# Django, bycrypt check password returns false

Tags: python, django

```
# coding: utf-8

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as UserDjango
from bcrypt import hashpw, gensalt, checkpw

from categories.models import User

import datetime

class Register(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        now = datetime.datetime.now
        password = request.data['password'].encode('utf-8')
        username = request.data['username'].encode('utf-8')
        email = request.data['email'].encode('utf-8').lower()

        if( User.objects.filter(email = email).count() == 1) :
            return Response( { 'success': False, 'message': 'Email registered previously' })
        else:
            hashed = hashpw(password, gensalt() )
            user = User(email=email, username=username, password=hashed, active='1', verified='0')
            user.save()
            return Response( { 'success': True, 'message': 'Succesful registration' })


class Login(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if(request.data['password'] == None or request.data['email'] == None):
            return Response( { 'success': false, 'message': 'Username and password needed' } )

        password = request.data['password'].encode('utf-8')
        email = request.data['email'].encode('utf-8').lower()

        user = User.objects.filter(email = email)

        if user.count() == 0 :
            return Response( { 'success': False, 'message': 'Email not registered' } )
```

But, at the moment to test it, I get the next error:

```
Internal Server Error: /user/login Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ben/peace/user/views.py", line 50, in post
    if( checkpw(password, passdb ) ):
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 107, in checkpw
    ret = hashpw(password, hashed_password)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 86, in hashpw
    raise ValueError("Invalid salt") ValueError: Invalid salt
```

When I try to debug it, I get the next parameters to test:

Database value: `'b'$2b$12$E0pbZeraqxjv3z2ZgVtz8.G7P03ANuhDvYq2/q037GtR3lAUd1Uxm''`
Database value printed in code: `b"b'$2b$12$E0pbZeraqxjv3z2ZgVtz8.G7P03ANuhDvYq2/q037GtR3lAUd1Uxm'"`

I'm not sure why is duplicating the `b` after the hash.

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't do this. Why are you doing this? Use `User.objects.create_user` or `user.set_password`.

Comment: The stack trace refers to this line of code `if( checkpw(password, passdb ) ):` which is not in the code sample in the question.  Please show us where this code is called.